# how to check if a class exists in selector or not Python scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, web-crawler, scrapy

This question has already been asked but I couldn't find any approved answer. So kindly don't mark it duplicate.

I'm new to scrapy and scraping an ecommerce website , I've to extract sizes of a product and mark them out of stock or not , my HTML structure is as follows

```html
<ul class="possible-sizes">
 <li class="available">35</li>
 <li class="not-available">36</li>
 <li class="available">37</li>
 <li class="available">38</li>
 <li class="not-available">39</li>
 <li class="available">40</li>
<ul>
```

I've extracted all the li tags using

```
response.css('ul.possible-sizes > li::text').extract()
```

But I want to set **out-of-stock** flag for he list items which have **not-available** class. Is there any way to do it as simple as possible.

Thanks in advance.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
response.xpath('//ul/li/@class | //ul/li/text()')
```

It will return a result like this:

```
['available', '35', 'not-available', '36', 'available', '37', 'available', '38', 'not-available', '39', 'available', '40']
```

Finally, you will be able to pair them and mark them out of stock based on **available** or **not-available** strings

---

Other approach would be to extract them separately:

```
response.xpath('//ul/li[@class="available"]/text()')
response.xpath('//ul/li[@class="not-available"]/text()')
```

Which would, respectively, return:

```
['35', '37', '38', '40']
['36', '39']
```

Comment: is there any css selectors way?

Comment: @F.Shahid CSS Selectors are on top of XPath selectors. Why would you want to use them over XPath selectors?

Comment: actually I'm using css selectors throughout the spider,

Comment: @F.Shahid you can use XPath selectors as well. I’d suggest to use them instead of CSS ones. In your question, you didn’t specified CSS selectors.

Comment: Should I write @class here response.xpath('//ul/li/@class | //ul/li/text()') or some specific class' name ?

Comment: @F.Shahid all the lines of code I submitted should work without any modifications

Comment: @F.Shahid my pleasure!